# Gremlin query to return all edge properties and also inV and outV

Tags: gremlin

Before the new ReferenceElementStrategy default setting, Gremlin query `g.E()` would return edge ID, label, inV, outV, and all the properties. What query should I use to return the same data with ReferenceElementStrategy enabled? `g.E().valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens).by(unfold())` returns everything except inV and outV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For right now the answer is `project()`:

```
gremlin> g.E(12).union(valueMap(true),
......1>               project('inV','outV','inVLabel','outVLabel').
......2>                 by(inV().id()).
......3>                 by(outV().id()).
......4>                 by(inV().label()).
......5>                 by(outV().label())).unfold().
......6>               group().
......7>                 by(keys).
......8>                 by(select(values))
==>[inV:3,id:12,inVLabel:software,weight:0.2,outVLabel:person,label:created,outV:6]
```

but for next release of 3.4.4 it will be `elementMap()`:

```
gremlin> g.E(11).elementMap()
==>[id:11,label:created,IN:[id:3,label:software],OUT:[id:4,label:person],weight:0.4]
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! This query works for a particular edge but doesn't really work for all edges. When I removed "12" from the above query, it returned results for one random edge. Is there a way to query all edges or all edges that have a specific label?

Comment: Gremlin traversals produce an `Iterator` so if you have multiple edges in your graph it should not produce one edge but all edges that you must iterate through with `next()`. Or you could terminate your traversal with something like `toList()` to iterate all edges to a `List` object and then access them through that object. If you want edges of a particular label you just need to filter them like `g.E().hasLabel('knows')`.